# Querying Perl Output

Tags: perl

I need to query on the 2nd line which I am seeing in the output. I need to check if the command returns on "Listener LISTENER is running on" and provide the desired output. My code is able to read the first line and not the second line which I need to verify. Please advise.

Added a While statement so it can read the 2nd line, did not work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $cmd="srvctl status listener";
my $listenerstatus0;
my $msg0;
my $msg1;
open(Row1Stat,"$cmd |") || die ("Could not read the pipe\n");
$listenerstatus0 = <Row1Stat>;
close(Row1Stat);
if( $listenerstatus0 =~ m/Listener LISTENER is running/)
{
$msg0="LISTENER is running";
$msg1=1
}
elsif ($listenerstatus0 =~ m/Listener LISTENER is not running/) {
$msg0 = "LISTENER is not running";
$msg1 = 0;
}
else {
$msg0 = "Unable to Query LISTENER Status";
$msg1 = 0;
}

print "\nStatistic.Name1:$msg1";
print "\nMessage.Name1:$msg0";
```

Below is the Output of the command, I need to check the 2nd line.

```
srvctl status listener
Listener LISTENER is enabled
Listener LISTENER is running on node(s): XYZ
```

The script needs to check "Listener LISTENER is running " and exit out with the exit code as defined in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read two lines you shouldn't stop reading after the first:

```
open(Row1Stat,"$cmd |") || die ("Could not read the pipe\n");
$ignorethis= <Row1Stat>;       # Read 1st line
$listenerstatus0 = <Row1Stat>; # Read 2nd line
close(Row1Stat);
```